# Folder Names Based on Filenames

Tags: batch-file

This isnt really a coding question. I need to put all my files into individual directories so each file has its own directory with the name based on the filename. 
So before i go make an application to do this, does anyone know any software that can do this? like Automator or something.

Comment: You should use automator or write a script that would do it.

Comment: ...you could use a shellscript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to build an application. This simple one liner run from the Windows command line will move each file in a directory into a sub-directory based on the root name of the file.

```
for %f in (*) do @(md "%~nf"&move "%f" "%~nf")>nul 2>&1
```

Two files with the same base name but different extensions will be moved into the same directory. For example, "test.txt" and "text.doc" will both be moved into a directory named "test"

Any file without an extension will not be moved.

If you want to run this from a batch file, then

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*) do (
  md "%%~nf"
  move "%%f" "%%~nf"
) >nul 2>&1
```

You requirements were not very clear. If your requirements differ, then the script can probably be modified fairly easily to suit your needs.

Comment: @Mechaflash - Depends on your definition of "one liner". :-) I agree it uses multiple commands, but I still consider it one line.