# Folder restructure script

Tags: bash, batch-file, directory, subdirectory

I have a directory which has *.txt,*.csv,*.xml files.

Original Folder Structure : `/Servicer/*.txt,*.csv,*.xml`

The file naming convention is as below :

```
 1. 6573547_BILLING_582524_1_00001.csv
 2. 6573547_BILLING_582524_1_00001.txt
 3. 6573547_BILLING_582524_1_00001.xml
 4. 6573547_BILLING_582524_1_00002.csv
 5. 6573547_BILLING_582524_1_00002.txt
 6. 6573547_BILLING_582524_1_00002.xml
 7. 6573545_BILLING_582524_1_00002.xml
 8. 6573545_BILLING_582524_1_00002.csv
```

My requirement is to create a folder structure as below and have the files inside the subfolders.

Required Folder Structure :

```
 /Servicer/6573547/582524_1/*.txt,*.csv,*.xml
 /Servicer/6573545/582524_1/*.txt,*.csv,*.xml
```

The script should be executable in Windows as well as Linux environment.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006354/folder-names-based-on-filenames but doesn't really fit the requirement

Comment: You should consider Python if you want multi-platform (Linux, Windows) support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script in BASH:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.@(csv|xml|txt); do
    IFS=_ read -ra arr <<< "$f"
    p="/Servicer/${arr[0]}/${arr[2]}_${arr[3]}"
    mkdir -p "$p"
    mv "$f" "$p/"
done
```

Comment: Maybe it's needs few modifications, it's creating subfolders for each file,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
I have modified the script a bit.

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
echo Process Started
for f in $1*.@(csv|xml|txt); do
    IFS=_ read -ra arr <<< "$f"
    p="${arr[0]}/${arr[1]}/${arr[2]}_${arr[3]}"
    mkdir -p "$p"
    cp "$f" "$p/"
        echo File $f is copied to $p
done
echo Process Finished
```

I want the script to read the foldername and create the subfolder with that name eg: 
 **D:\Test\Servicer1\*.csv,*.xml**

**D:\Test\Servicer2\*.csv,*.xml**

Now if i pass **"D:\Test\"** as an argument while execution, it should create a directory as below:

**\Servicer1\6573547\BILLING\582524_1*.csv,*.xml**

Meanwhile, I am trying for a solution, it'll be great if u can fix this.