# To create folders and copy images to it

Tags: image, copy, command, directory

I have a bunch of images with some random names. I need to create folders for each images with the same name as the images and copy to it.
Eg: lets say I have an image named "XYZ". I need to create a folder with the same and move this image to the newly created folder named "XYZ".
How can I do this?

Thank in advance.

Comment: are you asking about the generic idea? in this case you should remove the language I think. If you are asking a generic question for the specific language, instead, you are asking to implement the program on behalf of you and this is bad. If you specify a language, please put your code and specify what is the problematic part.

Comment: How would this be a generic, theoretical, language-agnostic question?

Comment: Yup. Any idea?
Could cmd prompt do this?

Comment: If you want to export that to Flash Player, so you can not create directories, and if you want to use that with an AIR app, you can use [`File.createDirectory()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#createDirectory()) ...

Comment: Not a flash player. Just a normal folder.

Thanks for your response,

Comment: @Sahal You'v mentioned the ActionScript 3 tag, so you are writing so for Flash Player (an swf file) so for AIR (an app) ...

Comment: Hey,
Really sorry about that, it was by mistake.

Comment: @GolezTrol you see? Astonished of how deep could be the rabbit's hole?

Comment: Okay. Point taken. :-)

Comment: I think the question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006354/folder-names-based-on-filenames